# How to show one page over another in custom way

Tags: 7, routes, modal-dialogs

I need to show one page over another for non-admin users much like

overlay feature in Drupal7 applicable for admin users. I tried out

overlay module and overlay UI module but not of much help.

All the overlaying pages are custom created and will be invoked on

working page after clicking a link.

Please refer me a solution which should work across all browsers and I

can adjust width and height of overlaying page.I want to implement this

solution for pop up messages, warning and alert also.Please see below

image for reference:

[image]

Need your much appreciated help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Popup](https://drupal.org/project/popup) module or [Lightbox](https://drupal.org/project/lightbox2)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using LightBox module now and I stuck again on a problem. Please find the link below:- http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84294/how-to-refresh-parent-window-and-close-lightbox-frame-automatically-after-submit. Please let me know your comments.